# API login React Not Connecting

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXjf1.jpg)I'm trying to login/register a new user, however, it won't let me and I have no idea how to get it fixed. What should I do about this? I tried to find out on how to do this but it is kind of getting complicated for me and I have no idea. It's like the code doesn't want to work.

```
enter code here
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoginForm from "../LoginForm";
import Auth from "../../utils/Auth";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router";
//Uses the Auth methods to actually login with the LoginForm Component.

function Login() {
  let location = useLocation();
  let history = useHistory();
  const [redirectToReferrer, setRedirectToReferrer] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/protected" } };
    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      history.push(from);
    }
  }, [redirectToReferrer, history, location.state]);

  /* We need to POST to the API the users info,
        This will get passed down as a prop to the LoginForm */
  const login = (data) => {
    console.log("Logging in " + JSON.stringify(data));
    //fetch('api/users/login', { is the error
    fetch("api/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          //All good
          Auth.authenticate(() => {
            //Update the boolean and take off the cuffs
            setRedirectToReferrer(true);
            console.log(`Response in login ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // No beuno, kick them
        console.log("Error logging in.", err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm onLogin={login} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help.

Comment: Code has been added: the part that troubles me is the fetch('api/users/login', {

Comment: also rename your question as it could get you downvoted because its too broad.

Comment: I renamed the question.

Comment: specify what is not working exactly. Being specific when posting questions is key.

Comment: When I try logging or registering a user, it wouldn't direct me to the account page. I used Google Chrome to discover the error. I try to find the solution, but it's not showing me much.

Comment: Can you log the `redirectToReferrer, from` inside `useEffect` and see if it is getting called? For testing purpose you can comment out api and do straight `setRedirectToReferrer(true);`

Comment: You mean like:  useEffect(setRedirectToReferrer(true) => {

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: '/protected' } }
  if (setRedirectToReferrer) {
   history.push(from)
  }

 }, [setRedirectToReferrer, history, location.state])

Comment: Just in case I added the image on the question, although it is embedded and it would say : enter image description here. The image contains the line up of the files added.